# basic mysql sha1 password valid check

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, sha1

I am using sha1 function to store my password in mysql DB..

```
$passwordHash = sha1($password);
```

From google I got this
From user registration

```
sha1( sha1(users_plaintext_password)+random string )
```

To check

```
server computes sha1( users_hashed_password_in_database +
$_SESSION['random_string'] )

if $_POST['password'] ==
sha1( users_hashed_password_in_database + $_SESSION['random_string'] )
```

My question is how do I check for validation?Is this the correct method?? And does using some random string as salt give my password more protection??

Comment: http://php.net/faq.passwords

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
$seed = 'some random string';
$passwordHash = sha1($password.$seed);
```

Then do the same with data entered by the user:

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];
if(sha1($pass.$seed) == $passwordHash){
    //log user in
}
```

The seed is a good idea, because users often pick passwords that are easy to guess. Another advantage is that you may be able to restore security to your site by changing the seed if someone manages to hack their way in.

Comment: Thank you for replying.. Good Day!!

Comment: You're welcome. I had an error in my code. I put the closing parenthesis for the sha1 function in the wrong place. Please check the edit.